# Does EOS RP support recomposing with servo AF?

Tags: canon, autofocus, mirrorless

My EOS RP has two AF modes: one shot AF and servo AF. With one shot AF, the
camera focuses once and allows recomposing the picture. With servo AF, the
camera keeps looking at the selected AF point, and refocusing continuously. So,
when I aim the camera at a near subject, half-press the shutter, and recompose
so that the AF point is at a far subject, the camera automatically refocuses to
the far subject.

However, I would like to have a mode where the camera keeps tracking the
subject that was initially at the AF point, and not tracking the AF point. So,
when recomposing, the focus point would move along with the subject / camera
movement.

I know the camera has touch & drag AF point selection and a huge number of AF
points, so it's not hard to select the AF point. However, I would find it
easier to just first aim the camera at the subject to be focused at, and then
recompose, which works with one shot AF but not with servo AF.

Is this recomposing with servo AF possible on this camera? Since the camera is
mirrorless, this kind of tracking should be easy for the camera manufacturer to
implement.

Comment: I think you are going to single-handedly write the book on this site regarding the RP.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible.

First, select the servo AF mode.

Then, select AF point to face detect + tracking.

Now with the previous settings, you won't see the AF point anymore in the
viewfinder or the LCD because it's doing face detect.

Then, set custom functions II-7: initial servo AF point for face detect +
tracking to the setting value 2 (AF point set for other modes).

Now the AF point became visible again.

This way, the subject at the autofocus point will be selected for tracking AF.
I think the face detection will probably be disabled in this custom functions
setting value.

When recomposing the picture, the camera will use sophisticated algorithms to
track the subject, even if the position of the subject within the frame
changes.

The only drawback with these particular settings is that the level indicator is
not visible anymore, so you may end up with a shot that is not perfectly level.

Comment: Yes, but was is the use case? Recomposing while shooting a moving subject?

Comment: I can see two use cases: (1) burst mode & moving subject, (2) recomposing & a really fast lens with minimal DoF, so minimal that camera movement means subject is not perfectly in focus.